# Uniqueness of darbha grass

Tags: scripture

It is a known fact that dharba grass absorbs radiation. Dharba ring is wore in different counts in different occasions? Why is it so?
On auspicious occasion dharba ring made of 2 grass is wore. On inauspicious occasions dharba ring made of 3 grass is wore. On kubabishekam to temples dharba ring made of 4 grass is wore. Any scriptural reference for this?

Comment: Good question @Parthasarathy Raghavan